# Replace certain columns in Dataframe with null

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to remove a certain columns based on high null values. In few columns there is a value(in this case "Select) which is equivalent to null. I want to replace this with null so that i can calculate the null % and removes columns accordingly.

```
Lead Profile    City
Select          Select
Select          Select
Potential Lead  Mumbai
Select          Mumbai
Select          Mumbai
```

Tried using replace function as well as map function.

```
leads['Specialization'] = leads['Specialization'].replace('Select', "NaN")
```

This Code just replaces the string with string and doesnt actually impute null values

```
def colmap(x):
     return x.map({"Select": "Nan"})

df[['Lead Profile']] = df[['Lead Profile']].apply(colmap)
```

This code replaces all the values with NAN

Comment: Try importing `numpy` and `df.replace('Select', np.nan)`

Comment: It is pandas that im using

Comment: pandas requires numpy, so you can safely add an `import numpy as np` statement.

Comment: Thanks guys for the insights. Will keep these in mind for all the null value situations going forward. cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to replace `value` with nulls:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].replace('value', np.nan)
```

otherwise to directly return only columns which have less than `N` times the `Select` values, you can use this:

```
df2 = df[[col for col in df.columns if len(df[df[col] == 'Select']) < N]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides Olivier's answer, in case you import data with `read_csv` or `read_excel`, these methods have `na_values` argument:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', na_values=['Select'])
```